# Time Out issue, can I set the Ping Property?

Tags: ssrs

I have some reports which I access through the Report Manager interface and view using a Report Viewer. If I leave a report open in the viewer then my session never times out. I believe this is because the viewer "pings" just before the session is due to time out, thus keeping the session alive.

This isn't very desirable and I would like to somehow set the viewer so that this "ping" doesn't happen. I have been trying to find a way to do this and have been coming up short as there is no obvious reference to this property in the config files or the site settings. I have found a number of references on the web to people having timeout issues using the reportviewer control in a .NET application, but none just using SSRS.

Is it possible to change this "ping" setting somehow? If so could somebody be so kind as to guide me through it as I am struggling.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the [`KeepSessionAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.keepsessionalive%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property of the [ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer_members%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control. To quote the linked MSDN page:

> **ReportViewer.KeepSessionAlive Property**
>
> **Property Value**
>   **true** to keep the user session from expiring; otherwise, **false**. The default is **true**.
>
> Setting this property to **true** causes the **ReportViewer** control to keep the ASP.NET session from expiring if session is enabled in your ASP.NET application. Also, in remote processing mode, it causes the **ReportViewer** control to keep the report server session from expiring.

You should be able to set this property to `false` to prevent the keep-alive calls.